# Firefox: certificate can’t be installed

Tags: tls, certificates

I would like to run an https C++ server from [this](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server) source code.

I have followed up [this](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) website to generate the certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
cp server.key server.key.org
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

which led to creation of four files:

```
server.crt
server.csr
server.key
server.key.org
```

Then, in my firefox browser, I go to preferences/advanced:

```
about:preferences#advanced
```

Then `view certificate`, `your certificates`, `import`.

[image: import certificate]

[image]

But at the end, I face with an error and nothing happens:

> This personal certificate can’t be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested.

[image: error]

All necessary file including `server.key` are there.

What is the problem?

What should I do?

Comment: It does not matter if the key is "there" - you did not offer it together with the certificate so the browser knows nothing about it. Just cat *.crt and *.key together into one file and import this:  `cat server.crt server.key > cert_and_key.pem`. Or just add the key to the certificate, i.e. `cat server.key >> server.crt`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I still get the same error when importing `cert_and_key.pem`: `This personal certificate can’t be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested.`

Comment: That certificate is supposed to authenticate the server, it's not supposed to authenticate you. You need to import it in server, not your certificates.

Comment: @user2313067, The server tab has no import button. It only has `add exception` button.

Comment: Are you trying to add a server certificate as a client certificate?

Comment: @BaconBrad, I have tried `authorities` tab as well. It does import the certificate but makes no effect. Firefox still gives warnings.

Comment: Have you tried importing from Authorities Tab?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It looks like that Firefox (and Chrome too) can only import key and cert together if they are inside a PKCS#12 file but not when they are in a PEM format. To create such a file from the created certificates:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12
```

Then import the server.p12 file in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It stores the password successfully but the connection is not secure: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33yye.png)

Comment: @ar2015: The certificate was successfully imported. What you ask now  is a different question and should not be asked as a comment. But I recommend that you look at the "Advanced" information offered. If these don't help you and you cannot find anything useful based on the information in Advanced please ask a new question and include the details from Advanced and the contents of your certificate.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is? Coming from a software engineering perspective, this is a blatant bug to me. Error message erroneously reports you don't have the matching private key when you clearly do, but the real problem is Firefox doesn't properly support PEM.

Comment: @GrantCurell +1. But it can get even worse: http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/errormsg.htm. 